# Checking bloc state with blocbuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm fetching a list of items from an API and building them using the BlocBuilder. It works and the widget list is built but when I print out to check which part of the state is being executed, I get as shown below. Why does 'Nothing' appeared ?

```
ProductInitial
fetching product //from bloc when fetching api
Nothing
fetching complete //from bloc after fetching api
ProductSuccess
```

**Main**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<ProductBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => ProductBloc()..add(FetchProduct())
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MainScreen(),
        )
      );
  }
}
```

**List Screen**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if(state is ProductInitial){
              print('ProductInitial');
              return buildLoadingWidget();
            }
            if(state is ProductSuccess){
              print('ProductSuccess');
              return _buildProductListWidget(state.products);
            }
            if(state is ProductFailed){
              print('ProductFailed');
              return Center(
                child: Text('Something went wrong'),
              );
            }
            print('Nothing');
            return buildLoadingWidget();
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

**Update**

Added the bloc code for reference.

**Bloc**

```
class ProductBloc extends Bloc<ProductEvent, ProductState> {
  ProductBloc() : super(ProductInitial());

  ProductRepository _repository = ProductRepository();

  @override
  Stream<ProductState> mapEventToState(ProductEvent event,) async* {
    
    if(event is FetchProduct){
      yield ProductLoading();
      try{
        print('fetching product');
        final List<ProductModel> products = await _repository.getProducts();
        yield ProductSuccess(products);
        print('fetching complete');
      }catch(e){
        yield ProductFailed();
        print(e);
        print('fetching failed');
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your events, states and bloc too?
for short answer: `Nothing` appears because you missed one possible state that you are yielding from bloc. if you catch that state using another if statement then you will not see Nothing.

Comment: see the update. thanks @Mahdi-Jafaree

Comment: you are catching all states but not catching the `ProductLoading` state inside your `blocBuilder` which is listening for new states. just add an `if( state is ProductLoading)` and handle it then `Nothing` will not be printed since you are catching all states.

Answer (score 1):

Update your bloc with the below code:

**BLOC**

```
class ProductBloc extends Bloc<ProductEvent, ProductState> {
ProductBloc() : super(ProductInitial());
   
 ProductRepository _repository = ProductRepository();

  @override
  Stream<ProductState> mapEventToState(ProductEvent event,) async* {
    
    if(event is FetchProduct){
      yield ProductInitial();
      try{
        print('fetching product');
        final List<ProductModel> products = await _repository.getProducts();
        yield ProductSuccess(products);
        print('fetching complete');
      }catch(e){
        yield ProductFailed();
        print(e);
        print('fetching failed');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As in your code, you are yield `ProductLoading` state but didn't handle that state in your BlocBuilder that's why it bypasses all if statement and prints **Nothing**.

So another way is handle `ProductLoading` in your block build as shown below

**List Screen**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if(state is ProductInitial){
                  print('ProductInitial');
                  return buildLoadingWidget();
                }
                if(state is ProductLoading){
                  print('ProductLoading');
                  return buildLoadingWidget();
                }
                if(state is ProductSuccess){
                  print('ProductSuccess');
                  return _buildProductListWidget(state.products);
                }
                if(state is ProductFailed){
                  print('ProductFailed');
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('Something went wrong'),
                  );
                }
                print('Nothing');
                return buildLoadingWidget();
              }
            )
          )
        );
      }
```

Comment: @stalwart1014 let me know if this not work for you

Comment: I think there is no need for yielding the `ProductInitial()` at first time since bloc itself will handle it.

Comment: @Mahdi-Jafaree yeah right that's why I added two options to correct this problem.